# Why do packages from library module does not exist upon compilation, even when Android Studio shows no errors in code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a library module (AndEngine) inside my libs/AndEngine folder.  The code from that compiles fine.

In my root settings.gradle file I have this :

```
include ':app:libs:AndEngine'
include ':app'
```

And then in my app's build.gradle file I have this in dependencies:

```
compile project('libs:AndEngine')
```

INside my app's code, all of the imports and even autocompletion works without any errors at all.  Inside Android Studio, all of the packages are found.  But when I go to compile, I get about a hundred of these errors:

```
error: package org.andengine.entity.primitive does not exist
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
```

I am coming from the ADK with eclipse, so I am new to android studio.  If anyone has any answers to this problem I would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line.

```
compile project('libs:AndEngine')
```

in

```
compile project(':app:libs:AndEngine')
```

In any case it is not a good idea to put a library module inside the app module.
I suggest you using this structure:

```
root
  settings.gradle
  app
    build.gradle
  libs
    AndEngine
      build.gradle
```

Then in your `settings.gradle`

```
include ':libs:AndEngine'
include ':app'
```

And in your `app/build.gradle`

```
compile project(':libs:AndEngine')
```

Comment: I've done exactly the same but errors won't go! What else might be wrong!