# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions

Tags: android, android-espresso

when trying to migrate to espresso 2.1 I hit the following road-block

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions$1;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

but I only see one source for this:

```
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.1'
```

any hint on how to solve this? This is the dependency tree:

```
androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.2
|    +--- junit:junit-dep:4.10
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
|    +--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0
+--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.1
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
|         +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|         +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1
|         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
|         +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.1
|         +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1
|         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
|         +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|         +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
|         +--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.2 (*)
|         +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.0
|    \--- info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.0
|         +--- info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.3
|         +--- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3
|         \--- info.cukes:gherkin:2.12.2
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.0
+--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0
|    \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.0
+--- org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1-TARGETFIX
+--- com.uphyca:android-junit4:0.5
\--- junit:junit:4.11
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: I added the dependency tree - unfortunately I cannot post the build.gradle

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29858606/950427

Comment: @JaredBurrows unfortunately not - but thanks

Comment: When you say migrate to espresso 2.1, is that from 2.0? When did this start?

Comment: when migrating from 1.1 to 2.1

Comment: Have you tried both suggestions in that link? That user had a similar issues when upgrading as well. Try BOTH of his solutions.

Comment: I tried only one - I cannot use espresso 2.0

Comment: You can't show the `build.gradle` and not you can't use espresso 2.0? You haven't even "used" it yet, you just upgraded to it.

Comment: @JaredBurrows not sure what you want to tell me - but here is a bit more background: https://plus.google.com/+misterligi/posts/EzCybiqDxft

Comment: "This post could not be found."

Comment: ah it is only in my android circles - now you are part of ti and should be able to read it

Comment: I commented. The source is included in "source.jar"s. So you have not tried espresso 2.0 because you think it does not support ham crest 1.3?

Comment: @JaredBurrows at this point in time the source was not available - and I tried 2.0 but it does not work with 2.0 - Stephan Linzner ( google ) was saying 2.1 could become 1.3 compatible - that's why I tried it out

Comment: Alright, I'll keep following, I want to learn why this is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

small world ;)

This DexException of Multiple dex files are caused indirectly by ***espresso-contrib:2.1***, the real root cause is ***com.android.support.test:runner:0.2***, which has some other sub-dependencies.

Removing ***test:runner*** works for me.

While there is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858606/1083611) saying it's because of ***com.android.support:support-v4***, in your case, it's ***22.0.0*** for the test, and maybe your app module is using different version.  So I tried to do:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: so your answer is something that actually does not work...

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu I'm just trying to analyze the problem, write down the clues and what is working or not.  Even if it doesn't work, it might still be helpful.

Comment: @JingLi What? That is a terrible reason.

Comment: Sorry @JaredBurrows, but what is a terrible reason?

Comment: Please keep comments to a minimum on StackOverflow. You want to add answers that are related to the question, which you did. I said it was a "terrible reason" because you said "Even if it doesn't work, it might still be helpful." which means you didn't even try **your own answer**.

Comment: Please read my original answer, I said "but it doesn't work at all.", why did you say "I didn't even try my own answer"?