# Android Espresso Issue - Dependency conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I'm trying to integrate espresso into my application for ui testing. Here are my dependencies in Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.3.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':service')
}
```

So all my espresso dependencies are included.  However when I try to build I get this error:

`Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (22.2.1) and test app (22.2.0) differ.`

Has anyone encountered this?  I've found it reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=136) however there's no resolution.  Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: The solution is to use  'configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0'
    }'

Comment: Hey, you have to remove android.support dependency from each espresso dependency.  check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857695/android-tests-build-error-multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-test-build

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So after a lot of digging around, I found I needed to change the dependency for the support annotations.

So I needed to change 
`compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'`
to
`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.+'`

Comment: i would suggest rather to use the approach i wrote in my reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807182/android-espresso-issue-dependency-conflict/41160902#41160902 since using the "+" for versioning is discouraged

Answer (score 35):

New version of **`espresso-contrib 2.2.2`** library has now dependency on `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` resulting into conflict when using different version of `appcompat-v7` in our `compile` time dependency like below:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
}
```

To avoid conflict when we exclude `appcompat-v7` dependency from `espresso-contrib` like below it breaks again due to some value dependencies on `design support` lib.

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Error:

> Error:(69) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.

So, the solution to above problem is to exclude 'design-support' lib depedency from `espresso-contrib` like below:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'design'
}
```

That solves the conflict problem!

For more detailed version of the answer you could check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484833/2819262)

Comment: @Droidwala that was the best answer

Answer (score 8):

Latest versions of `androidTest` dependencies depend on appropriate version of `support-annotations` lib. In my case it is:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.31-beta'
```

Also, as a workaround you can add the next code in your `build.gradle`, `android{}` section:

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
       force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
   }
}
```

Comment: Adding configurations.all { .. } worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I know that this answer will solve the problem. But every support-annotations version may rely on diferent methods, So be very carefully because the libs that depends on support-annotation may act strange.

Answer (score 7):

In the [Jake Wharton U2020 application](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020) it is solved in the next way

Add to you `gradle.build` file

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to combine the following versions for L release after receiving a similar dependency conflict between project and test app:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {    
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
}
```

useLibrary was needed since we use org.apache.http imports, see https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android/issues/80

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this file:
android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\test\runner\0.3\runner-0.3.pom

here:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

if you set 22.2.1 instead 22.2.0 it will work

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the google documentation:
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Resolving-conflicts-between-main-and-test-APK

The way to resolve is to explicitly set the support library in `androidTestCompile` to the version you are using in the project.

if for example you are using support library version `25.0.1` just add

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
```

in your `build.gradle` configuration

Answer (score 0):

just change  compile `com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0` to `23.0.1`
if want to use 2.2.1 version