# Android espresso-contrib gradle build failing

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm  trying to learn android espresso.. I followed some basic tutorials and it was working fine. But now I want to do some tests on the android navigation drawer. For that I need to use gradle dependency **androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'** but it's causing conflict with other dependencies. My gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.com.myapp_android"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
jcenter()
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//material design
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'

//zxing
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

//Testing
// Optional -- Mockito framework
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
// Optional -- Hamcrest library
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
// Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
// Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'




//inMarketSDK
//compile group: 'com.inmarket', name: 'm2msdk', version: '2.29', ext: 'aar'

}
```

Error is something like this:

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'. Resolved versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'. Resolved versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

followed this : [link](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/) for espresso install

I also tried to exclude annotation dependency :

```
 androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')  {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2')
        {
            // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
            // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
```

Comment: Error message says conflict with `com.android.support:support-v4` and `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`. So try to exclude them too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

New version of **`espresso-contrib 2.2.2`** library has now dependency on `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` resulting into conflict when using different version of `appcompat-v7` in our `compile` time dependency like below:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
}
```

To avoid conflict when we exclude `appcompat-v7` dependency from `espresso-contrib` like below it breaks again due to some value dependencies on `design support` lib.

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Error:

> Error:(69) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.

Root cause:

> This is because the `design` support lib has dependency on
>   `appcompat-v7`.
>   So,when we exclude 'appcompat-v7' module from 
>   `espresso-contrib`  dependencies(like above) , the `design` support lib downloaded as
>   part of transitive dependency of `espresso-contrib` lib couldn't find
>   the compatible version of `appcompat-v7 lib(23.1.1)` it is using
>   internally in its resources files and thus gives out the above error.

So, the solution to above problem is to exclude 'design-support' lib dependency from `espresso-contrib` like below:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'design'
}
```

That solves the conflict problem!

**LONGER VERSION** (in case someone is interested):

To found out the reasons of various conflict issues we face when using `espresso-contrib' library i have created sample app to find out the root cause.

```
Step 1:Using Espresso-Contrib Lib version 2.2.1
```

Created App to use **'espresso-contrib'** lib version **2.2.1** by adding following lines in `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'
```

}

Note: In this case,I am not importing any other support library components like
`appcompat-v7,recyclerview-v7,etc`.

The dependency graph for the above setup looks like below:
[image]

As can be seen that `espresso-contrib 2.2.1`lib has transitive dependencies on version 23.0.1 of
`support-v4`,`recyclerview-v7`,`support-annotations` ,etc.

As i am not defining dependencies for `recyclerview-v7`,`support-annotations` in my project the above setup would work just fine.

But when we define those as compile dependencies [like below] in our project we get version conflict issues as stated in your question.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

To avoid those conflicts we add below line to our espresso-contrib lib:

```
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

This makes sure those dependencies aren't downloaded as part of `espresso-contrib` transitive dependencies.
Everything runs fine with above setup.No issues!

```
Step 2: Using Espresso-Contrib lib version 2.2.2
```

Changed App's build.gradle to use **'espresso-contrib'** lib version **2.2.2** by changing the previous build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
  }
}
```

But when i build project using above setup..build fails with error posted in question..

Error:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'. Resolved versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

So, looking at error i added one more line to above build.gradle:

```
exclude module: 'appcompat-v7' (inside androidTestCompile block of espresso-contrib)
```

But that doesn't resolves the conflict issue and i get value dependencies error posted in comments.
So i check for dependency graph of my app again:
[image]

As can be seen now that `espresso-contrib 2.2.2` lib has now transitive dependency on `com.android.support:design:23.1.1` causing the above conflict.

So, we need to add below line inside `androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2')` block:

```
exclude module: 'design'
```

This resolves the conflict issue in lib version 2.2.2!

Comment: waw... Perfect answer. Thank you. @Droidwala

Comment: @D4Developer I'm glad i could help:) You can click green tick to mark this as accepted answer so that it helps users coming across this question in future.

Comment: Perfect answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The best answer I saw here, solved my hours long quest. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, it has also started to happen to me out of the blue.

The only thing that solved it was to **invalidate caches and restart**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do below

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried excluding but when I write this `exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'` it brakes some values dependencies.

Comment: I tried this ` transitive = false` and it worked , though. But not sure if this is a good solution