# faild to resolve errors on android studio core:2.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Got this 4 errors:

```
Error:(23, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:24.0.0
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0
```

The code:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adir.remember"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
}
```

How can I fix errors above?

Comment: did you add the dependency for above lib's.? post your gradle

Comment: please share your project level and app level build.gradle file

Comment: @RajuSubramanian i'm a begginer.. how can i find it?

Comment: @ShaileshLimbadiya i'm a begginer.. how can i find it?

Comment: you just update your lib else share you whole error code

Comment: please provide a screenshot & build.gradle file content !

Comment: see http://imgur.com/a/0inZu

Comment: @ShaileshLimbadiya added

Comment: format errors text

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko edited the post above. got some new errors if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html) about configure build for more about refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio)

Then, in your gradle add the following lib's

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Hope it will help.!

Comment: Tryed to edit it with your solution , didn't work. added the all code

Comment: did you syn after added the above lib's.?

Comment: Yes, it's just gave me the same errors but for the above lib's

Comment: which version classpath you using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0' this is latest version do you have this

Comment: didn't really understand the question..did you mean my gradle version ?       if so it's 2.14.1

Comment: there is two gradle project and module. do you have updated the latest build tool version in project gradle

Comment: Two days ago it showed me that i need to update things so i just pressed update and let it finish to update everything

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure about your library, because your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` both are different so please set same, its not required but its better for us. Your `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` library version is also different. Please set `compileSdkVersion 24` and `buildToolsVersion 24.0.0` same. I suggest that use `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` and your every library version will be same .
In my case i used as below and it's working fine for me

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    }
    ...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'design'
        module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I edited the code as you said , everything is 24 still it's giving me errors like: Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:24.0.0
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0

Comment: Have you update that library in your SDK ? if you not then please update it. please share your error message screen short

Comment: please see my updated answer else please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307671/android-espresso-cotrib-gradle-build-failing/37484833#37484833

Comment: it's giving me a new error : "Error:(30, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'module' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: Edited the post.. got some new errors after trying to change things.. would be awesome if you can help me

Comment: I suggest you that you just Update your SDK and reinstall your android studio 2.2 and create one simple project and check is it ok or not ?