# Recording an Espresso test with a DatePicker

Tags: android, android-espresso

The test recorder produces code that promptly fails on being run after recording.

The reason is that while recording, I tap the year, the year spinner pops up, I scroll back and then select one of the years. The recorder does not capture the scrolling.

In Xcode, they added a method to scroll to the item. I could not find something akin in Espresso.

(Using Android Studio 2.3.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have not used the recorder in a long time and instead wrote my tests by hand.

I use the following line to set the date in a [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker):

```java
onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))).perform(PickerActions.setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));
```

The [PickerActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/PickerActions) class is defined in the [espresso-contrib](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib) library. Add it as follows to your gradle file:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
```

I then use this in a helper method which clicks the button that opens a [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog), sets the date and confirms it by clicking the OK button:

```
public static void setDate(int datePickerLaunchViewId, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    onView(withParent(withId(buttonContainer)), withId(datePickerLaunchViewId)).perform(click());
    onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))).perform(PickerActions.setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));
    onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
}
```

And then use it in my tests as follows:

```
TestHelper.setDate(R.id.date_button, 2017, 1, 1); 
//TestHelper is my helper class that contains the helper method above
```

Comment: Wait, what is PickerActions? Should that be TestHelper?

Comment: sry my bad, that is an extra library taking care of the picker. i updated my answer

Comment: ok thanks, wow the recorder is so useless.. painful.. will try this, but god so much trouble to do something that should be simple... :(

Comment: yeah i tried the recorder a good year ago and decided it's a nice gimmick but not yet ready for real usage. I hoped that it evolved in the meantime but from your response i guess it is still not that much better. generally i am happy with writing my tests manually, i think i can keep them much cleaner that way (and i know exactly what they try to do and what not)

Comment: But even that requires SO MUCH additional garbage, I hate how verbose it is. I thought Kotlin might help, does not seem to... yet at least.

Comment: Your exclude did not work but this question fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307671/android-espresso-cotrib-gradle-build-failing/37484833#37484833. Thanks. Works otherwise. Though the paging does not work (added another question for that).

Comment: oh yeah i didn't want to copy the whole exclude since i was not which entries are really needed and which depend on your specific gradle file

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This answer is intended to supplement [@stamanuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739696/1071320).

To see an example in the Android source code of an Android instrumentation test which opens a [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog) and selects a date, refer to the [PickerActionsTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/PickerActionsTest.java) file.

The two key lines of code in that file are the following:

```java
// Sets a date on the date picker widget
onView(isAssignableFrom(DatePicker.class)).perform(setDate(1980, 10, 30));

// Confirm the selected date. This example uses a standard DatePickerDialog
// which uses
// android.R.id.button1 for the positive button id.
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
```

As [@stamanuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2567799) has mentioned in his answer, the [PickerActions.setDate(year:monthOfYear:dayOfMonth:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/PickerActions#setDate(int,%20int,%20int)) method is defined in the [androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib) library.