# Select Date from Calendar in Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am testing an Android app with Espresso.  I have an `EditText` widget with `androidInputType=date`.  When I touch this control with my finger, a calendar pops up for me to select the date.

How do I automate this in Espresso?  I've looked all over the place and I can't figure it out.  `typeText()` certainly does not work.

Comment: can you show the ids and their data type. calendar id which you need to click.

Comment: Just saw that my answer below seems to help other people as well. If it solved your problem it would be nice if you could accept it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 27):

Original answered by me here, but in the scope of another question: [Recording an Espresso test with a DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739315/recording-an-espresso-test-with-a-datepicker/42739696#42739696) - so I repost my adapted answer from there:

Use this line to set the date in a datepicker:

```
onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))).perform(PickerActions.setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));
```

This uses the `PickerActions` which is part of the espresso support library - the `espresso-contrib`. To use it, add it like this to your gradle file (You need several excludes to prevent compile errors due to mismatching support library version):

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Then you could create a helper method which clicks the view that opens the datepicker, sets the date and confirms it by clicking the ok button:

```
public static void setDate(int datePickerLaunchViewId, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    onView(withParent(withId(buttonContainer)), withId(datePickerLaunchViewId)).perform(click());
    onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))).perform(PickerActions.setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));
    onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
}
```

And then use it like this in your tests:

```
TestHelper.setDate(R.id.date_button, 2017, 1, 1); 
//TestHelper is my helper class that contains the helper method above
```

Comment: I had to replace "2.2.2" with "2.2" to avoid build conflicts.

Comment: Note: 
the `PickerActions.setDate` can pick a date which is disabled for the user.

Comment: In order to make it work, I had to use `isAssignableFrom(DatePicker.class)` instead of `withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))`