# How to select date from the Textview in Expresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

```
onView(withParent(withId(buttonContainer)),withId(datePickerLaunchViewId)).perform(click());
```

In the above line, I get "Cannot resolve symbol buttonContainer". What is expected there?

In my case, I use a TextView of "inputType=date" and i'm not sure where to perform a click.

I'm tried using the code from here [Select Date from Calendar in Android Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149728/select-date-from-calendar-in-android-espresso?rq=1) and have this in the same class.

---

```
onView(isAssignableFrom(DatePicker.class)).perform(PickerActions.setDate(2020, 06, 01));

setDate(R.id.button8, 2017, 1, 1);

public static void setDate(int datePickerLaunchViewId, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        onView(withParent(withId(buttonContainer)),withId(datePickerLaunchViewId)).perform(click());
        onView(isAssignableFrom(DatePicker.class)).perform(PickerActions.setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));

        onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`withId` takes a resource ID, which you must reference from the `R` class. So in your case it'd most likely be `R.id.buttonContainer` instead of just `buttonContainer`.