# Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (25.3.1) and test app (23.1.1) differ

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

I get this error every time i am trying to add dependency of Esspreso UI test library by the following dependency to use it in developing UI test for RecyclerView to get RecyclerViewActions.

```
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
```

while deleting previous dependency gradle is building perfectly 
can anyone help me selving this problem??
Sample from my gradle :

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'

        compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0'

        androidTestCompile( 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        androidTestCompile( 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        androidTestCompile( 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

    }
```

> Update
>
> After googling for an hour I found the solution within [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTestingEspresso/article.html) by
>   setting this dependency as following:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
```

Comment: You can run a dependency report, as is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Espresso Issue - Dependency conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807182/android-espresso-issue-dependency-conflict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would solve your problem:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

You need to just exclude every library you have already provided in `build.gradle`

Comment: this is the same solution i found after hours of googling but using :
com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2
 not 2.2.2