# Data Model class is not visible to my AndroidTest classes while is visible to main project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

My project contains two modules. Main App module and SDK module. I have following lines of code in `Build.gradle` file of App module.

```
dependencies {
    releaseCompile project(path : ':Sdk', configuration : 'prodRelease')
    debugCompile project(path : ':Sdk', configuration : 'prodDebug')
    testCompile project(path : ':Sdk', configuration : 'mockDebug')
...    
}
```

Therefore, the Sdk must be visible to the whole of my App module. I have no problem in my project which is under `main` folder. However, I'm trying to write Espresso test cases in order to test my activity and I need to create a model. The model resides somewhere in Sdk module. I thought this module must be visible to `androidTest` class too but seems does not. Even I wrote `import` address manually but it still does not recognizable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found what was my problem.
By adding following line, SDK module got visibility to my `androidTest` classes.

```
androidTestCompile project(path : ':Sdk', configuration : 'prodDebug')
```

More explanation [at here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688159/513413).