# Android Studio: Instrument Tests Cannot Find junit, mockito, or hamcrest

Tags: android, cordova, unit-testing, gradle, junit

Our project uses Cordova which has customized the build.gradle file in the following way:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
}
```

I read the documentation on setting up Instrument tests and configured my gradle file as directed:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':CordovaLib')
    // other deps

    // !! THIS IS THE INSTRUMENT SETUP!
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

I've sync'd the gradle and the external libs folder does have all the junit and hamcrest and mockito files. Further proof is given that it has autocomplete when I go to import them into my test class (which is set correctly at `src\androidTest\java`:

```
package co.appname.app.Utils;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ColorsTest
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        assertThat(2, is(2));
    }
}
```

But when I go to compile or run the test I get

> Error:(5, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist
>
> Error:(6, 24) error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
>
> Error:(7, 27) error: package org.mockito.runners does not exist
>
> Error:(9, 24) error: package org.hamcrest does not exist

I set up a new project (and didn't modify the source sets) and my Instrumentation tests run just fine.

I figure something must be up with my source sets. So I read the docs on [setting up a gradle file](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) and the testing section in particular.

The only thing I could find relevant is this paragraph:

> As mentioned previously, next to the main sourceSet is the androidTest sourceSet, located by default in src/androidTest/. Using this sourceSet a test APK gets built, which can be deployed to a device to test the application using the Android testing framework. This can contain android unit tests, instrumentation tests, and uiautomator tests. The  node of the manifest for the test app is generated but you can create a src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml file to add other components to the test manifest.

However, I tried setting that in my gradle file like such:

`androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTests/java')` Didn't work

`androidTest.setRoot('tests')` Didn't work

`androidTest.setRoot('androidTests')` Didn't work

My project cannot seem to find the junit files and I suspect it has *something* to do with my source sets being moved (because as I said my test project did run the instrumentation tests) but I have no clue what to do to fix it. If you have any advice (even a cryptic idea of where I might be able to look) I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `compile` instead of `androidTestCompile` fixes this issue. Looks like a bug in Android with projects using modified source sets.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a few hours - I had no idea what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it with `setRoot`.

You "only" have to combine it with `java.excludes = ['androidTest/**']` so the folder is "freed" from the main sourceSet:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.excludes = ['androidTest/**']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }
}
```

Now you can use `androidTestCompile` correctly.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259738/252627